# Grab Id from asp.net and use in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I'm trying to learn c# and asp.net webforms and am working on an application that is similar to how reddit or facebook might function.  Users have the ability to create accounts, send and accept friend requests, leave wall posts etc.

I have implemented the ability to send a friend request, but am stuck on the part where a user can accept the request.  Here is the c#:

```
 using (Database.DataModelDataContext db = new Database.DataModelDataContext())
        {
            //Guid RequesterId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            CRANK.Database.Friendship RequestAccept = new Database.Friendship

            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UserA = base.UserId,
                UserB =

            };

            db.Friendships.InsertOnSubmit(RequestAccept);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

So as you can see, UserA would be added to the database with the logged-in users ID.  I can't figure out how to get the information for UserB or the person that the original friend request was sent from.  I'm assuming we can somehow grab it from the code in asp.net.

Comment: Here is some of the asp.net code: 
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="fhID"       Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfProfileID" Value='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' />
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lblRequesterName" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:HyperLink><br />
                            <br />

sorry for the bad formatting! Wasn't sure how to fix it.

Comment: You should be storing `UserB`'s user id in the initial friendship request.

Comment: As I assume it is stored in the hfProfileID hidden field. So you can access it using hfProfileID.Value. UserB = hfProfileID.Value;

Comment: I don't know if I can because here is how the original request is being sent: 

I get the receivers id by this: 
Guid pageUserId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
and use base.UserID for the sender.

Comment: If you haven't got a something like a FriendRequest object, create one. Then create a new table to store all pending FriendRequests. In here, you would have a column for UserA, a column for the id of person that sent the request UserB along with any other relevant data. When a request is accepted you update the pending table, removing the record for that request and create a new one in a `Friends` table for that user. Similarly, if you ever need to access pending friend requests for a user, you just query the pending requests table for that user.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding it.  I do have a table that holds all the requests, as well as one that that stores friends.  I don't really know how to query the database for that specific requester's id.  Sorry I'm a bit new to c# and sql.  I feel like Kiran Hegde is pretty close with the answer though, but I get an error saying we can't use a null value.  hfProfileID is the id for the requester.  Is there a good way to call that in c# and save it to my table as UserB? Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ID was stored in a CommandArgument.  I used this code:

```
Guid userRequested = Guid.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

UserB = userRequested
```